# scraping website for info when the URL has product id's instead of true values

Tags: php, linux, web-scraping

Im guessing its php cURL, but Whats the best way to make a loop to scrape the DOM for info from a webpage that uses id's in the URL Query like (?ProductId=103) There is about 1200 pages. I need to find the innerHTML of the 9th span on each page. This info will just get stored in a mySQL table (id->value) for future scraping of this site.

Comment: the scraping part has been answered before better => for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885760/scraping-and-web-crawling-framework-php. You should search => http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+web+scraping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well curl might be faster (not sure), but if it is a one off thing, then I would just use file_get_contents

```
for($x=0;$x<1200;$x++){
  $f = file_get_contents(URL . '?productId='.$x);
  #do stuff to $f
 }
```

Comment: Make sure to add a check that the page received has a product and not a 404, so you don't get bogus data.

Comment: cURL can do a lot of useful things in crawling though, like following redirect headers and returning cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use cURL to retrieve the page, use a DOM parser like SimpleXML to get the info you need out of it.

Answer (score 0):

## cURL

to speed things up you could use multi_curl =>

```
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+multi_curl
```

## scraping

the scraping part has been answered before better => for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885760/scraping-and-web-crawling-framework-php.

You should search => `https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+web+scraping`

## mySQL

I don't know if you do, but you should be using [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) to make it safe(SQL-injections).